# Error karma on watch => ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am running test on a angular-cli projects =>

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (C:\Users\myusername\git\myproject\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:14022:110)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\myusername\git\myproject\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13961:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (C:\Users\myusername\git\myproject\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13873:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (C:\Users\myusername\git\myproject\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13712:29)
    at new TypeScriptFileRefactor (C:\Users\myusername\git\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\refactor.js:79:35)
    at Object.findLazyRoutes (C:\Users\myusername\git\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\lazy_routes.js:18:22)
    at AotPlugin._findLazyRoutesInAst (C:\Users\myusername\git\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:217:50)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\myusername\git\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:496:24)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

I have this error. It works normally on first run, but crash with this error, when i modified any file. It used to work perfectly.

My package.json is like this

```
{
        "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
        "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.3",
        "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
        "karma": "~1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
        "typescript": "2.7.2"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood is that you have a typescript file or a folder missing.

There are other potential solutions too, they can be found on [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5053) on the angular-cli github issue page